# A step in the proof that two solutions of an IVP must coincide in the intersection of their domains

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $ F $ be a Banach space (for our purposes $ \mathbb R^n $ will suffice), and let $ U\subset F $ be an open set. Let $ I\subset \mathbb R $ be an open interval. Let $ X\colon U\times I\to F $ be a continuous and locally uniformly Lipschitz function. Let $ (x_0,t_0)\in U\times I $.

I've already shown that there exist an open interval $ J\subset I $, an open subset $ U_0\subset U $ and a unique curve $ \gamma\colon J\to U_0 $ such that $ \gamma(t_0) = x_0 $ and such that $ \dot\gamma(t) = X(\gamma(t),t) $ for every $ t\in J $.

Now I'm trying to show that any two curves $ \gamma_1\colon J_1\to U_1 $ and $ \gamma_2\colon J_2\to U_2 $ such that $ J_1\cap J_2\neq \emptyset $ coincide on the intersection of their domains. The textbook I'm following is *Advanced Calculus* by L. H. Loomis and S. Sternberg.

The proof goes like this. Let $ A $ denote the set of all the $ t\in J $, $ t > 0 $ such that $ \gamma_1(t)\neq \gamma_2(t) $. Then $ A $ is bounded and it makes sense to let $ t_0^\prime = \sup A $. We also know that $ A $ is also open, since both the $ \gamma $s are continuous, thus $ t_0^\prime\not\in A $. At this point the authors claim that $ \gamma_1(t_0^\prime) = \gamma_2(t_0^\prime) $. But how do they know that $ t_0^\prime $ is again in the intersection $ J_1\cap J_2 $?

The rest of the proof is clear to me (or at least I think so), but I can't figure out this detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misread the proof. Define $J=J_1\cap J_2$ and
\begin{align}
A=\{t\in J\,:\,\text{$t>t_0$ and $\gamma_1(t)\neq \gamma_2(t)$}\},
\end{align}
where $t_0$ is by hypothesis a given point in both $J_1$ and $J_2$, so $t_0\in J$ as well.
They assumed for contradiction that $A$ was non-empty, so it contains an element $s$. Since  $A$ is non-empty and bounded below (by $t_0$) it has an infimum; we can define $t_0’:=\inf A$. Note they did **not** define it to be the supremum.

Since $t_0$ is a lower bound for $A$, and $s\in A$, it follows that $t_0\leq t_0’\leq s$. Finally, since $J$ is the intersection of two intervals, it is again an interval, and therefore by virtue of it containing $t_0$ and $s$, it must contain $[t_0,s]$ and hence contains $t_0’$.

Comment: Thank you! My error was hilarious indeed:)

Comment: well, glb doesn’t help, since in my mind I see g and think greater and hence sup.

Comment: Also, I don’t like this particular way of writing the proof. I much rather phrase things positively and  say let $E=\{t\in J\,:\gamma_1(t)=\gamma_2(t)\}$, i.e consider the equality set in $J$. This is non-empty since $t_0\in J$. It is closed in $J$ since $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ are continuous. It is open in $J$ due to the ODE theorem. Therefore, since $J$ is and interval and hence connected, we must have $E=J$ (by definition of connected). As you can see from this phrasing, it is mostly a topological result; the only place where ODE theory comes in showing openness in $J$.

Comment: I like your proof. It actually does answer a question I was asking myself yesterday. If I take two solutions $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ defined respectively on $J_1$ and $J_2$ then using a fixed-point argument I can find a subinterval $J\subset J_1\cap J_2$ where $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ coincide. I was wondering if this fact could be used in some way to prove that $\gamma_1 = \gamma_2$ on the whole intersection $J_1\cap J_2$. Your proof seems to say "yes"!